# Ruby on Rails: can I use http basic auth in constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constraints, basic-authentication

I use Rails 5 API mode

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do      
  constraints Basic do
    mount Rswag::Ui::Engine  => '/api-docs'
    mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
    mount Sidekiq::Web       => '/sidekiq'
    # etc
  end
end
```

constraints/basic.rb:

```
class Basic
  def self.matches?(request)
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |email, password|
      email == 'foo' && password = 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic' for Basic:Class)

Can I use http basic auth in constraints?

Comment: Also here is what I found [rails-authentication-routing-constraints-considered-harmful](https://anadea.info/blog/rails-authentication-routing-constraints-considered-harmful)

Comment: good explanation, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think you can use [`authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic) method out of controllers scope. You can set up `before_filter` with auth check in general controller. Here is an example taken from [docs comments](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic#62-Easy-and-effective-admin-authentication):

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |email, password|
      email == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

---

Also here is what I found [Rails Authentication Routing Constraints Considered Harmful](https://anadea.info/blog/rails-authentication-routing-constraints-considered-harmful).

---

That being said I think there is a way:

```
class Basic
  def self.matches?(request)
    if ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.has_basic_credentials?(request)
      credentials = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.decode_credentials(request)
      email, password = credentials.split(':')

      email == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

[Here is docs on HTTP Basic authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) with examples